# Anyone know movies with references to Plato?

Tags: plato

I’m interested in Plato and would like to know if there are any movies with references to some of his theories/ideas, 
Thanks 
Ben

Comment: I suppose The Matrix could be connected with Plato's cave metaphor.

Comment: Interstellar (2014), Shutter Island (2010), Synecdoche New York (2008), Pan's Labyrinth (2006), Stranger Than Fiction (2006), The Village (2004), The Truman Show (1998), Strangers on a Train (1951)...etc. There are many themes in Plato's works: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Creator/Plato

Comment: Did you try googling "plato movies"? It brings up a [long list](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&q=plato+movies&oq=plato+movies&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1l3j0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1l2.1190849.1193207.0.1193415.15.13.0.0.0.0.98.912.11.11.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..4.11.910.0..0i131k1.0.jcclCPheE8g).